# How do I prevent Google Apps Script from forwarding sent email to the forwarding address

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using MailApp.sendEmail to send mail FROM:SEND@example.com and TO: RECEIVE@example.com

The SEND@example.com inbox automatically forwards all incoming mail to various other addresses in my organization.

The unintended consequences are that even though I only want these emails to be delivered to RECEIVE@example.com, they are automatically being forwarded to all of the email addresses that SEND@example.com forwards to as well.

This doesn't seem logical, as it is an outgoing email and if I simply send an email from the SEND@example.com inbox normally, the sent mail does not get forwarded.

Can anyone explain why this happens and/or a way around it?

Comment: Can you post your `MailApp.sendEmail` code

Comment: I think this a recent change in functionality. It affected my long-running scripts yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it happens because the copy google's servers (running the apps script) places in the sending account's mail folders is treated by gmail as a new incoming message that just happens to have the from field set to be that account itself. It then performs whatever rules it always performs on incoming messages.

You can set your rules for that gmail account to forward except in the case that the from address is your own email address. When you create the filter enter "-SEND@example.com" in the from field.